# fadeIn() and then animate (multiple id's) simultaneously using jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

I can think no more. I would appreciate if someone could help me get through this problem. I have, say, 6 cubes, which I want to fade in one by one to the screen and then spread out simultaneously. I am making use of `fadeIn` and `animate` method. Here is my code,

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentBox">
        <svg id="polyWhite" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-white" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-white" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-white" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyBlack" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-black" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-black" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-black" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyRedTwo" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-red-two" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-red-two" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-red-two" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyBlackTwo" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-black-two" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-black-two" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-black-two" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyRedThree" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-red-three" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-red-three" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-red-three" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyBlackThree" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top-black-three" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right-black-three" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left-black-three" />
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg id="polyRed" width="200" height="270" viewBox="0 0 512 606">
            <g>
                <polygon points="256,343 47,195 256,55 465,195" class="top" />
                <polygon points="256,343 465,195 465,480 256,627" class="right" />
                <polygon points="256,343 256,627 47,480 47,195" class="left" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("svg").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeIn(300);
    });
    $("#polyRed").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "-23",
        top: "9"
    });
    $("#polyBlack").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "140",
        top: "-102"
    });
    $("#polyBlackThree").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "-22",
        top: "233"
    });
    $("#polyBlackTwo").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "304",
        top: "233"
    });
    $("#polyRedTwo").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "305",
        top: "10"
    });
    $("#polyRedThree").delay(2000).stop().animate({
        left: "140",
        top: "345"
    });
```

I get the animation simultaneously, but then I lose the delay in fadeIn. Some jQuery experts can help me with what is going wrong.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle??

Comment: Appear to be _seven_ hexagons ?

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/ . I want each hexagon to fade-in one by one. Then make that animation occur simultaneously.

Comment: Check my answer... It should help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/3/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 close enough :) But the fade-in triggers all the hexagon at once. If you could make it one-by-one, we will be good.

Comment: I hope this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/4

Comment: @ThomasSebastian See post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are asynchronous in execution. You have to call the next animation (by opacity is just same as using fadeIn) at the end of the previous element's animation.

This would help you I guess

```
var allSVGs = $("svg");
fadeIn(0);

....

function fadeIn(svgIndex){
   allSVGs.eq(svgIndex).animate({"opacity":"1"}, {
   complete:function(){
      svgIndex++;
      if(svgIndex < allSVGs.length) //Making sure we don't exceed the maximum available SVG elements
         fadeIn(svgIndex); //Recursively calling the next elements animation (hide) from the completed one.
   }});
}
```

**Edit**
See this [jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/4/). I just commented the other areas of code to make things little easier...

Comment: My fade-in works the way I want if I comment the code for animate. I want both to work, not just fade-in. Once the fade-in is done, I want them to be animated to different positions, that too simultaneously.

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/4/ this version has both fade-in and position moving one after the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You read my mind. Thanks a lot. I ll implement it on my code and accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#parentBox").queue("boxes", $.map($("#parentBox svg"), function(el, index) {
    return function(next) {
        $(el).delay(400 * index).fadeTo(1000, 1, next)
    }
})).dequeue("boxes").promise("boxes")
.then(function() {
  $("#polyRed").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "-23",
    top: "9"
  });
  $("#polyBlack").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "140",
    top: "-102"
  });
  $("#polyBlackThree").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "-22",
    top: "233"
  });
  $("#polyBlackTwo").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "304",
    top: "233"
  });
  $("#polyRedTwo").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "305",
    top: "10"
  });
  $("#polyRedThree").delay(2000).stop().animate({
    left: "140",
    top: "345"
  });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ame17p3b/6/